# LiveCharts not showing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, livecharts

I have tried to implement LiveCharts in vb.net project but unsuccessful. Tried searching the internet but unfurtunately found no sample code. What might be the problem in my code?[sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9feE.png)

```
    Private Sub InitializeChart()
    Dim labelPoint As Func(Of ChartPoint, String) = Function(chartPoint) String.Format("{0} ({1:P})", chartPoint.Y, chartPoint.Y, chartPoint.Participation)
    'pieChartMain = New LiveCharts.WinForms.PieChart
    Dim seriesCollection As SeriesCollection = New SeriesCollection
    Dim pieSeries1 As PieSeries = New PieSeries
    Dim pieSeries2 As PieSeries = New PieSeries
    pieSeries1.Title = "MALE"
    pieSeries1.Values = New ChartValues(Of Double) From {3}
    pieSeries1.PushOut = 15
    pieSeries1.DataLabels = True
    pieSeries1.LabelPoint = labelPoint

    pieSeries2.Title = "FEMALE"
    pieSeries2.Values = New ChartValues(Of Double) From {6}
    pieSeries2.DataLabels = True
    pieSeries2.LabelPoint = labelPoint

    seriesCollection.Add(pieSeries1)
    seriesCollection.Add(pieSeries2)
    pieChartMain.Series.Add(seriesCollection)

    pieChartMain.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Bottom

    pieChartMain.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the sample needs more information to someone try a help...

**What is the PIE control name?**

**Are you IMPORTING the libraries?**

```
Imports LiveCharts.WinForms
Imports LiveCharts.Wpf
Imports LiveCharts
```

After the last PieChart command, try to force the redraw. For instance, in a Gauge control, I get success if utilize:

```
Gauge.resumelayout
```

So, try to REFRESH and also RESUMELAYOUT over the control

Comment: tnx David but i ended using the default graph in .net maybe i be revisting livechart other time.

Comment: No problem at all @jbElmas2012. Good luck.